# SVG to JPEG via PHP4

Tags: svg, php4

I am currently struggling with a side project I hope you can help me with.

I am trying to convert SVG images to JPEG with PHP4.

Originally I tried to [interface java with php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/java.installation.php) via the php_java.dll and jar that comes with PHP 4.2.2 but while I never got any warnings I never managed to get even the simplest test working. All text regarding it is for JDK1.4 and an [article on setting it up on O'Reilly website](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/06/14/php_jav.html) is for JDK1.2. That would of enabled me to use [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/).

So I then looked harder and saw cryptic references to using [PHP:GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to convert SVG to JPEG. GD seems to be able to load and save JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc, but not SVG directly. GD seems to use a vector graphics format but not entirely sure if it is SVG compatible (I am a noob to both).

I did find a [Perl GD::SVG module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD-SVG/), but obviously requires Perl - and considering the problems I had with PHP<->Java I am loathe to go that route.

I also found a site (which I can't find now) that discussed speed of various SVG conversions with rsvg, Cairo and a couple of others.  Talking of applications converting SVG to JPEG, people also discuss [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). While that might work on the linux box that is the server, I do 99% of my development in Windows - hence prefering a pure PHP solution and not wrestling with differences between applications on different platforms.

I am now considering writing a SVG->GD converter. The final alternative is to use SVG in the browser via [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/). I'd rather convert to JPEG on the server and serve the image normally.

**Has anyone had any use of SVG->GD, know of any OS (but not GPL) convertors or have any better ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to fix it by actually downloading and installing the 1.4 JDK from Sun's archive.  Worked no problem.  Something must of changed between 1.4 and 1.6.14 but I am glad I got it working.

Also while researching a blog post on this subject I came across Image_Canvas which might be a better (ie it is written in PHP) option.

Answer (score 1):

It's not maintained, and I can't vouch for it, but you didn't mention this option. It sounds like what you were trying to do with Batik.

http://pear.php.net/package/XML_svg2image/

Don't know if this helps or not.

Comment: That was what I was trying to do with Batik.